# Possible causes for 302 TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS? (Drupal 9 installation)

Tags: php, drupal, apache2.4, drupal-9

I have a problem today.

I'm trying to install Drupal 9.0.7 on a server, but when I select a installation language other than english, I get an error screen telling me that there's been too many redirects.

[Error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2PSo.png)

I already enabled AllowOverrides, which did make a change since before the link only said [www.example.com/core/install.php?langcode=es](http://www.example.com/core/install.php?langcode=es) and now it says [www.example.com?rewrite=ok&langcode=es](http://www.example.com?rewrite=ok&langcode=es)

But I still get the same error screen.

Here's a comparison of what the network debug tab is supposed to look like (Up) vs what it actually looks like (Down).

[Comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eskKA.png)

So... I'm kinda running out of ideas here, is there any other setting I should check for it to work?

Comment: Just for sanity's sake, can you try another browser? I have personally been stuck in a redirect look many times, specifically with Chrome, because it tends to "remember" redirects, even if it doesn't receive them.

Comment: Ugh! That is such a good advice, but no, same result in other browsers, and even with Chrome I run Ccleaner frequently exactly for that reason. :(

Answer (score 0):

Someone (bbu23) made a patch that actually works! - https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3158071